# Facebook default video player into Android webview

Tags: facebook-graph-api, android-webview, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-iframe

I want to stream facebook video using default video player of facebook in my app. On click of video i want to open webview in my app and play facebook video by using their own video player and all default control. How will i achieve it? Is their any other way to achieve the video streaming. But i want to stream video using facebook default player and not on any other player. How can i achieve this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please visit [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

Did you already double check dev facebook docs [embedded-video-player/api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api), where you can find this following full code example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '{your-app-id}',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });

      // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
      var my_video_player;
      FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;
        }
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
  <div  
    class="fb-video" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" 
    data-width="500" 
    data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Assuming that you put this code in your webview, it will normally work like a charm.

Comment: OK but how can I put data-href as dynamic video url? Here you data-href is fixed for one video

Answer (score 1):

For loading a dynamic URL

First Replace with this in your html

```
--> data-href="{video_url}"




`mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"
                + populateHTML(R.raw.my_html), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);private String populateHTML(int resourceID) {
        String html;
        html = readTextFromResource(resourceID);
        html = html.replace("{video_url}", dynamic_url);
        return html;
    }`

    private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID) {
        InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;
        try {
            i = raw.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                stream.write(i);
                i = raw.read();
            }
            raw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream.toString();
    }
```